# Как вычитать и посчитать сумму элементов большой матрицы?

Tags: c++, матрицы

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b, i, j, sum;
    int m[a][b];
    cout << "Vvedite kolichestvo strok ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Vvedite kolichestvo stolbcov ";
    cin >> b;
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            cout << "Vvedite element ";
            cin >> m[i][j];
        }
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
            sum += m[i][j];
    cout << "Summa elementov matrici = " << sum << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a, b, i, j, sum;     int m[a][b];` Чему на ваш взгляд равны размеры матрицы `m`?

Comment: Размеры матрицы равны значениям параметров a, b/

Comment: Ну, допустим, а чему конкретно равны `a` и `b`?

Comment: Имеете ввиду присвоить им значение 0 на этапе объявления?

Comment: А знаете что? Сработало. Большое вам спасибо - выручили! Всех вам благ

Comment: Воу-воу, не так быстро! Хоть некоторые компиляторы и могут скомпилировать такое: `int a, b, i, j, sum;     int m[a][b];`. Это вообще говоря не валидный код. Размерности массива должны быть константными выражениями. Либо объявите `m` как-то так: `int m[10][100]`, либо выделяйте память динамически с помощью `new`, либо используйте `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: Переходите на Си. Там есть VLA.

Comment: Вам следовало задать вопрос вида: "Как вычитать и посчитать сумму элементов большой матрицы?"

Answer (score 1):

Сначала уберите

```
int m[a][b];
```

Исправьте `int sum` на `int sum = 0`

Потом, после `cin >> b;` напишите

```
int ** m;
m = new int*[a];
for(int i = 0; i < a; ++i) m[i] = new int[b];
```

И это

```
        cout << "Vvedite element ";
        cin >> m[i][j];
```

замените на

```
        cout << "Vvedite element ";
        cin >> m[i][j];
        sum += m[i][j];
```

Это

```
for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
        sum += m[i][j];
```

выкиньте.

Ну и допишите освобождение памяти сами.

Это все если нужна матрица, а вообще сумму можно посчитать и без нее, при вводе.

Что вы хотите вычитать, я так и не понял.