# Как исправить ошибку с масивами с++

Tags: c++

Как исправить ошибку(Выражение должно иметь константное значение)в 17 и 33 строке, не знаю как исправить!:)  Помогите пожалуйста!

```
    int main() {
        //Оголошення масивів--------------------------------------------------------
        int A = 0, B = 0;
    
        cout << "Enter Size A  =" << " ";
        cin >> A;
    
        cout << "Enter Size B =" << " ";
        cin >> B;
    
        cout << '\n';
        //------------------------------------------
        int arrA[A];
        // заповнюємо масив А
        for (int i = 0; i < A; i++) {
            cout << "arrA[" << i << "]:";
            cin >> arrA[i];
        }
    
        // виводимо масив А
        cout << "\n ===== arrA: ";
    
        for (int i = 0; i < A; ++i) {
            cout << arrA[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << '\n';
        //-----------------------------------------
        int arrB[B];
        // заповнюємо масив В
        for (int i = 0; i < B; i++) {
            cout << "arrB[" << i << "]:";
            cin >> arrB[i];
        }
    
        // виводимо масив В
        cout << "\n ===== arrB: ";
    
        for (int i = 0; i < B; ++i) {
            cout << arrB[i] << " ";
        }
    
        cout << endl;
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
        int match = 0, notmatch = 0;
```

Comment: создавайте массивы динамически

Comment: А и В должны быть константным выражением, если являются размерами статического массива

Comment: Вот недавний вопрос с такой же проблемой: [Как вычитать и посчитать сумму элементов большой матрицы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1190451).

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
int arrA[A];
```

на

```
int * arrA = new int[A];
```

и также точно для B